# How Do I Move To a Different ViewController?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.2

I was wondering how to make a UITableView go to a different ViewController when you press a cell. So far I have this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row == 0) {       
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It goes something like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        SomeViewController *newController = [[SomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:newController animated:YES];
        [newController release]; // leave this line out if using ARC
    }
}
```

WARNING: Just typed the above without looking at any documentation -- if it doesn't compile after you substitute your own view controller class name for `SomeViewController`, look for misspellings and such.

BTW, there's quite a bit of documentation on this topic, and plenty of examples too. If the snippet above doesn't solve your problem, take a look at the [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH1-SW1).

Comment: +1 Very nice answer showing a lot of patience.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is so basic as to be unanswerable, or rather an answer would be meaningless if you don't have a grasp of some of the basic iOS concepts. I would highly recommend that you spend a few hours going through the videos of the [Standford iOS programming class on iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255?mt=10) (free).

If you are a registered developer, Apple also has many excellent videos from WWDC detailing the basic design patterns involved. There are also some decent videos on YouTube.

And of course look at source code - from Apple, the Standford class, or the many good tutorials on this site (http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials)